# SQL Query, query to having single field name from different table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, select, join

I have two table with some identical field. (please don't blame the design).
Below only for the example schema

> Table A
>   id
>   name
>   phone
>   keys
>
> Table B
>   id
>   name
>   keys
>   address

So, i want to query id, name from either table A or B which meet condition 'keys' on single query, with return Field just "ID" and "NAME" no matter it's from tableA or tableB
with simple query

> SELECT a.id, a.name, b.id, b.name FROM TABELA as a, TABLEB as b  WHERE a.keys = '1' or b.keys = '1'

It return duplicate id, name, id1, name1 to the result field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `UNION` instead of `CROSS JOIN`:

```
SELECT a.id, a.name
FROM TABELA as a
WHERE a.keys = '1'
UNION 
SELECT b.id, b.name 
FROM TABLEB as b
WHERE b.keys = '1'
```

Answer (score 1):

use union or union all. Union returns only distinct rows, union all returns all rows

see examples in manual [manual on unions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html)

```
SELECT a.id, a.name FROM TABELA as a WHERE a.keys = '1' 
union
SELECT b.id, b.name FROM TABELb as b WHERE b.keys = '1'
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not actually joining tables, but you just want to combine the result of two different queries. We have UNION SELECT for that:

```
SELECT id, name FROM tableA
    WHERE keys = '1'
UNION SELECT id, name FROM tableB
    WHERE keys= '1'
```

If you want to order the result, you can use above as a subquery.